# Proper casual english for someone experiences of a song or movie

Tags: word-choice

How do you guys say it if a movie/song's story happens to someone. Is it

> She *experiences* the song/movie (<-- this is more like *she sings/watches it*?)

or

> She *encounters* the song

or

> The song's story happens to her.

*?* I'm not sure with those sentences, though. How do you guys usually say it? I need in British and American style.

Comment: Are you asking how we would describe a situation where what happens to us in our lives mirrors the plot of a movie or the circumstances of a song?

Comment: Yes, like, the song tells story about her.

Comment: She is living that song.

Comment: It's one way to say it. Most people would understand it to mean that the circumstances of her own life mirror those in the song.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a phrase that generally describes such a relationship:

> Art imitates life.

meaning that what is portrayed in art forms reflect on (and are often closely related to) the actual lives of people. Such relationships could be purposeful or accidental.

For example, a while after the movie [Twister](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117998/?ref_=nv_sr_1) was released, a real tornado struck the town where the "hollywood" tornado struck in the movie.